# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS File Manager problem on saving

Tags: firefox, gui, filemanager

When saving a PDF file from Firefox:
A.

1. I type filename
2. Then select directory where the files needs to be saved.
   What happens:
   B.
3. The directory path populates the path window
4. The filename I typed is overwritten

This does not happen if the order in A is reversed.

This is annoying as I have followed A for many years without problem.
A screenshot is available.[See how the directory path overwrites filename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZSyF.png)

Comment: As you already provide the workaround in your question, this sounds more like a bug report that should be reported here https://launchpad.net/firefox,  than a question for askubuntu

Comment: Clarify how you select directories. If I type a file name, then use the navigation controls under the file name to select a directory, the file name is preserved. Add the information to your post: use "edit".